# Putting an individual contact's calls on do not disturb

Tags: iphone, ios, contacts

Here's my problem...I have one contact who will call me 4 or 5 times in a row to "be sure" I really can't talk. They're driving me NUTS. But I'm job hunting and don't want all my calls to go directly to voicemail...is there any way I can put just this person on DND?

The thing is, I don't want to hurt their feelings by "ignoring" their calls every time. I'd rather them think my phone is off completely. I read that going into messages and turning off notifications would work, but it didn't. I've tried talking to them about it, but they aren't getting the hint and I don't want to resort to being mean.

Comment: I have a silent ringtone and a custom no vibe vibration for a similar purpose that I assigned to one contact.  I can see they called from notifications but don’t get interrupted.  Sadly there is no good solution for when you’re on the phone, you’re still going to hear the call waiting tone.

Answer (score 1):

There is a 3rd party app called YouMail. The free versiin of it will allow you to set different conditions for different contacts. You can change which voicemail message someone gets. You can send a certain contact directly to voicemail. And you can also prevent callers from being able to leave a voicemessage. I had someone who would also call me 4-8 times in a row and no matter how many times I asked him to stop and explained why, he just kept doing it. With him, I would vary between the silent ringtone strategy mentioned by Tyson and YouMail’s ditch call.

Comment: Be nice to have sn app that can answer and hold a « fake » conversation - 3 or 4 stock phrases that you record... then they talk thinking its really you...

Comment: Ha, yes. Well timed "mhmm"s. Actually with the state of those AI callbots, it's probably doable, if someone would release the code. I had one insist to me that she was not a robot. "I. Am. Not a. Robot. There is a real. Person. Here."